# How to dynamically/programmatically set the Enterprise Library Database Trace Listener connect string

Tags: azure, enterprise-library, tracelistener, trace-listener

Is there a way to dynamically/programmatically set the connection string the EntLib 5 database trace listener utilizes?

I am hosting my WCF service in Windows Azure, which means I will not have access to the web.config once it is deployed. In order to eliminate the need to redeploy my solution whenever I want to point the DB trace listener at a different DB I was hoping there would be a way I could pull that setting from my service configuration file and set it dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [the fluent configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#fluent_api_logging) as described [in this post](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/270338):

```
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();
builder.ConfigureData()
        .ForDatabaseNamed("MyDb")
        .ThatIs.ASqlDatabase()
        .WithConnectionString(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("MyConnectionString"))
        .AsDefault();

builder.ConfigureLogging()
        .WithOptions
        .LogToCategoryNamed("General")
        .SendTo
        .Database("Formatted Database TraceListener").UseDatabase("MyDb")
        ...;

var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

Comment: If I have all of my logging configurations setup in the .config file, am I able to just set the connection string without having to do the builder.ConfigLogging()... step?

Comment: Even if I add the ConfigureLogging() portion, the logger is still using the connection string from the web.config of my service and not the value I am setting dynamically in the code.

Comment: If you already have an existing instance of the LogWriter, this won't change it. Try getting a new one or doing the container reconfiguration first.